# Angular2 Child Component with OPTIONAL Input

Tags: angular, components

## TLDR: Can an `@Input` be optional?

So i have this child component which is a modal for creating a Transaction (in bank terms), and i want to upgrade this modal to be create-or-update Transaction.

Currently the modal is just a group of input fields and a submit button for creating.
What i want to achieve is when this component gets a transaction as an input, it will be on 'edit-mode' and when it does not it will be on 'create-mode' (meaning the input field will be already filled with data in edit-mode and empty on create-mode)

Can an `@Input transaction` somehow be optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Even more, simply do this in case you want changes

```
<div *ngIf="transaction">Some edit stuff</div>
<div *ngIf="!transaction">Create stuff</div>
```

If you want specific stuff

```
ngOnInit() {
  if(!this.transaction) { 
    // create stuff only 
  } else {
    // update stuff only
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: how I would do it (in your case)

This may not be the best solution, but should work (if I didn't get the syntax wrong)

```
ngOnInit() {
  if(!this.transaction) { 
    this.transaction = new Transaction();
  } 
}
```

this way all class properties will be available, only empty. Unless you want them predefined, you can set them in a constructor, or in ngOnInit.

Comment: What i don't want to happen in my template is having double elements, i simply want the `<input>` to be filled with data or not, therefore I wanted to work with an optional `@Input` , you said it is possible, how can i achieve it then?

Comment: I edited. I really don't know if this is a good solution, but something like this works for me

Comment: I see, so that way I'll be able to place a `<create-update-transaction [transaction]="this.transaction></create-update-transaction` as well as `<create-update-transaction></create-update-transaction>`?

Comment: That's the idea

Comment: So i've had success with what you have suggested, only i did not check the input in the constructor and initialized the Input on the property declaration like this: `@Input() transaction: Transaction = new Transaction()` , it works fine, thanks alot :)